# Get values from variable in function and apply second conditional

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, jupyter-notebook

I have this function,

```
def compare_date(x):
    if pd.to_datetime(x) < pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01'):
        return pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01')
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime(x)

file['Cash Received Date'] = file['CASH RECIEVED DATE'].apply(lambda x: compare_date(x))
```

that returns `file` as:

```
  CASH RECIEVED DATE Cash Received Date
0         2018-07-23         2019-09-01
1         2019-09-26         2019-09-26
2         2017-05-02         2019-09-01
```

However, I need change the dates so they get the value of two variables that are `Year` (in format *yyyy*, it can be any year) and `Month` (in format *MM*, it can be any month), so I thought to change my function to something like this, that didn't work:

```
def compare_date(x):
    if pd.to_datetime(x) > pd.to_datetime(Year + '-' + Month + '-01'):
        return pd.to_datetime(Year + '-' + Month + '-01')
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime(x)

file['Cash Received Date'] = file['CASH RECIEVED DATE'].apply(lambda x: compare_date(x))
```

I tried to convert `Year.astype('string')` and `Month.astype('string')` and it didn't work either.

Furthermore, I'd like to add a second conditional to this function that if the column `file['Policy']` is *X* then change dates as per above, else copy value of `file['CASH RECIEVED DATE']` to `file['Cash Received Date']`

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem is that you cannot use a lambda as you need to apply an operation to obtain your new column taking into account the value on several columns. You can still use apply method but as shown on code snippet below:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"month": ["10", "11", "12"],
                               "year": ["2020", "2018", "2021"],
                               "cash_received_date": ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"]})

def compare_date(row):
    if pd.to_datetime(row["cash_received_date"]) > pd.to_datetime(row["year"] + '-' + row["month"] + '-01'):
        return pd.to_datetime(row["year"] + '-' + row["month"] + '-01')
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime(row["cash_received_date"])

file['Cash Received Date'] = file.apply(compare_date, axis=1)
```